# How to serve static assets with Rack::App?

Tags: ruby, rack

I am trying to make [Rack::App](https://github.com/rack-app/rack-app) serve static files from the folder `public/` (like possible with Sinatra using `set :public_folder, 'public'`).

Is this supported out of the box? If not, how to do it in the simplest way?

Comment: "If you want to see fancy magic, you are in a bad place buddy!" - the readme. The simplest (and most performant) way would be to use the web server (NGiNX or Apache) to do the job for you.

Comment: Some servers (i.e., `iodine` and `agoo`) offer an integrated static file service... but I would still recommend using NGINX or Apache. There's no need to delay static assets until after the pending dynamic requests are done.